# Remove date in images's url on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

When I upload images in Wordpress I get:

```
   http://test.net/wp-content/uploads/image name**-20210601-071141**.jpg
```

however I would like it like this:

```
 http://test.net/wp-content/uploads/image name.jpg
```

See how the **date and 071141**  isn't in the URL on the 2nd one? That does not happen for all images that I upload but that happens only for some images
Anyways, is that possible? To remove the what is between **  **date** and that **code** stamp from the Image URL?

Notice that On Media Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders is **UNCHECKED** and even I remove the old images and  regenerate the thumbnails again . I get the same problem !!! I don't have any pluging can do something on images

Comment: That looks like those are now the image names,nothing to do with the url?  It is not normal wordpress behaviour to change the image names like that.  If an image with same name already exists, wp will add a digit.  And of course the thumbnails have the dimensions added  to the name.  Do you have any plugins that do anything to the images?   Try deactivating those plugins and then upload an image and see what happens then.

Comment: I désactivâte all suspuct plugins can do anything on images but no result . I still having the same problem :(

Comment: If anything was affecting permalinks one often also needs to refresh the permalinks by navigating to the permalinks menu option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can apply rule in .htaccess file

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://yourwebsite.com/$3

Comment: Really I dont know how to do this :(